# Bootstrap Dropdown Closes Whole Menu On Mobile Only

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Evening! I am having an issue with a Bootstrap menu: Only on mobile (like only on Apple devices) whenever you click the Bootstrap dropdown, it closes the whole menu. Then when you click on the hamburger button again, the dropdown is expanded. This doesn't happen on Chrome, Firefox, or Safari when I shrink the window size...

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="primary">
                    <div class="desktop-nav">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>
                            <a href="http://latva.itwebdev.net" class="link-logo"><img class="logo img-responsive img-left" src="http://latva.itwebdev.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/logo.png" alt="Logo" />
                            <h1>Latva Machine, Inc.</h1>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse"><ul id="menu-header" class="nav navbar-nav"><li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-111" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-51 current_page_item menu-item-has-children menu-item-111 dropdown active"><a title="Services" href="http://latva.itwebdev.net/services/" data-hover="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle disabled" aria-haspopup="true">Services <span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu" >
    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-112" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-112"><a title="CNC Machining" href="http://latva.itwebdev.net/services/cnc-machining/">CNC Machining</a></li>
    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-113" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-113"><a title="Casting &#038; Forging" href="http://latva.itwebdev.net/services/forging-casting/">Casting &#038; Forging</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-110" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-110 dropdown"><a title="Materials" href="http://latva.itwebdev.net/materials/" data-hover="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle disabled" aria-haspopup="true">Materials <span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu" >
    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-145" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-145"><a title="Titanium" href="http://latva.itwebdev.net/materials/titanium/">Titanium</a></li>
    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-140" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-140"><a title="Inconel®" href="http://latva.itwebdev.net/materials/inconel/">Inconel®</a></li>
    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-141" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-141"><a title="Molybdenum" href="http://latva.itwebdev.net/materials/molybdenum/">Molybdenum</a></li>
    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-139" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-139"><a title="Hastelloy®" href="http://latva.itwebdev.net/materials/hastelloy/">Hastelloy®</a></li>
    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-142" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-142"><a title="Monel®" href="http://latva.itwebdev.net/materials/monel/">Monel®</a></li>
    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-144" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-144"><a title="Stainless Steel" href="http://latva.itwebdev.net/materials/stainless-steel/">Stainless Steel</a></li>
    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-138" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-138"><a title="Aluminum" href="http://latva.itwebdev.net/materials/aluminum/">Aluminum</a></li>
    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-687" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-687"><a title="Nitronic 60" href="http://latva.itwebdev.net/materials/nitronic-60/">Nitronic 60</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-104" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-104 dropdown"><a title="Industries" href="http://latva.itwebdev.net/industries/" data-hover="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle disabled" aria-haspopup="true">Industries <span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu" >
    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-105" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-105"><a title="Aerospace" href="http://latva.itwebdev.net/industries/aerospace/">Aerospace</a></li>
    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-109" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-109"><a title="Military" href="http://latva.itwebdev.net/industries/military/">Military</a></li>
    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-108" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-108"><a title="High-Tech" href="http://latva.itwebdev.net/industries/high-tech/">High-Tech</a></li>
    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-107" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-107"><a title="Firearms" href="http://latva.itwebdev.net/industries/firearms/">Firearms</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-103" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-103"><a title="Contact Us" href="http://latva.itwebdev.net/contact-us/">Contact Us</a></li>
<li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-147" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-147 dropdown"><a title="About Us" href="http://latva.itwebdev.net/about-us/" data-hover="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle disabled" aria-haspopup="true">About Us <span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu" >
    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-301" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-301"><a title="Facilities &amp; Equipment" href="http://latva.itwebdev.net/about-us/facilities-equipment/">Facilities &#038; Equipment</a></li>
    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-572" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-572"><a title="Parts Gallery" href="http://latva.itwebdev.net/gallery/">Parts Gallery</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul></div>    
                    </div>
                    <div class="mobile-nav">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-mobile" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar-mobile">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>
                            <a href="http://latva.itwebdev.net" class="link-logo"><img class="logo img-responsive img-left" src="http://latva.itwebdev.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/logo.png" alt="Logo" />
                            <h1>Latva Machine, Inc.</h1>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div id="navbar-mobile" class="collapse navbar-collapse"><ul id="menu-mobile" class="nav navbar-nav"><li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-642" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent menu-item-has-children menu-item-642 dropdown"><a title="Services" href="#" data-hover="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle disabled" aria-haspopup="true">Services <span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu" >
    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-639" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-51 current_page_item menu-item-639 active"><a title="Services" href="http://latva.itwebdev.net/services/">Services</a></li>
    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-641" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-641"><a title="CNC Machining" href="http://latva.itwebdev.net/services/cnc-machining/">CNC Machining</a></li>
    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-640" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-640"><a title="Casting &#038; Forging" href="http://latva.itwebdev.net/services/forging-casting/">Casting &#038; Forging</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-644" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-644 dropdown"><a title="Materials" href="#" data-hover="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle disabled" aria-haspopup="true">Materials <span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu" >
    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-643" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-643"><a title="Materials" href="http://latva.itwebdev.net/materials/">Materials</a></li>
    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-645" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-645"><a title="Titanium" href="http://latva.itwebdev.net/materials/titanium/">Titanium</a></li>
    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-646" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-646"><a title="Inconel®" href="http://latva.itwebdev.net/materials/inconel/">Inconel®</a></li>
    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-647" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-647"><a title="Molybdenum" href="http://latva.itwebdev.net/materials/molybdenum/">Molybdenum</a></li>
    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-648" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-648"><a title="Hastelloy®" href="http://latva.itwebdev.net/materials/hastelloy/">Hastelloy®</a></li>
    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-649" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-649"><a title="Monel®" href="http://latva.itwebdev.net/materials/monel/">Monel®</a></li>
    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-650" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-650"><a title="Stainless Steel" href="http://latva.itwebdev.net/materials/stainless-steel/">Stainless Steel</a></li>
    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-651" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-651"><a title="Aluminum" href="http://latva.itwebdev.net/materials/aluminum/">Aluminum</a></li>
    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-686" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-686"><a title="Nitronic 60" href="http://latva.itwebdev.net/materials/nitronic-60/">Nitronic 60</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-652" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-652 dropdown"><a title="Industries" href="#" data-hover="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle disabled" aria-haspopup="true">Industries <span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu" >
    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-657" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-657"><a title="Industries" href="http://latva.itwebdev.net/industries/">Industries</a></li>
    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-653" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-653"><a title="Aerospace" href="http://latva.itwebdev.net/industries/aerospace/">Aerospace</a></li>
    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-654" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-654"><a title="Military" href="http://latva.itwebdev.net/industries/military/">Military</a></li>
    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-655" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-655"><a title="High-Tech" href="http://latva.itwebdev.net/industries/high-tech/">High-Tech</a></li>
    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-656" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-656"><a title="Firearms" href="http://latva.itwebdev.net/industries/firearms/">Firearms</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-659" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-659"><a title="Contact Us" href="http://latva.itwebdev.net/contact-us/">Contact Us</a></li>
<li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-661" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-661 dropdown"><a title="About Us" href="#" data-hover="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle disabled" aria-haspopup="true">About Us <span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu" >
    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-660" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-660"><a title="About Us" href="http://latva.itwebdev.net/about-us/">About Us</a></li>
    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-662" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-662"><a title="Facilities &amp; Equipment" href="http://latva.itwebdev.net/about-us/facilities-equipment/">Facilities &#038; Equipment</a></li>
    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-663" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-663"><a title="Parts Gallery" href="http://latva.itwebdev.net/gallery/">Parts Gallery</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul></div>    
                    </div>                  
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Custom JS:

```
(function($){
    //edit 2018-12-07
    //prevent mobile menu parent item anchoring or linking to show submenu
    $('ul#menu-mobile').on('click','a.dropdown-toggle.disabled',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var parent = $(this).closest('li');
        var active = $('ul#menu-mobile li.show-submenu');
        if(active.length == 0){
            parent.addClass('show-submenu');
        }else{
            if(parent.hasClass('show-submenu')){
                parent.removeClass('show-submenu');
            }else{
                active.removeClass('show-submenu');
                parent.addClass('show-submenu');
            }
        }

    });
})(jQuery)
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    jQuery('.carousel-showmanymoveone .item').each(function(){
        var itemToClone = $(this);

        for (var i=1;i<3;i++) {
            itemToClone = itemToClone.next();

        if (!itemToClone.length) {
            itemToClone = $(this).siblings(':first');
        }

        itemToClone.children(':first-child').clone()
            .addClass("cloneditem-"+(i))
            .appendTo($(this));
        }
    });

    jQuery('.carousel-showmanymoveone-1 .item').each(function(){
        var itemToClone = $(this);

        for (var i=1;i<2;i++) {
            itemToClone = itemToClone.next();

        if (!itemToClone.length) {
            itemToClone = $(this).siblings(':first');
        }

        itemToClone.children(':first-child').clone()
            .addClass("cloneditem-"+(i))
            .appendTo($(this));
        }
    });

    $('.show-hidden a').on('click' , function(){
        $(this).closest('.work').find('.load-hidden').css('display' , 'block');
        $(this).hide();
    });

    fixedMenu = function(){
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        if(scrollTop > 0){
            $('header nav').addClass('fixed-active');
        }else{
            $('header nav').removeClass('fixed-active');
        }
    };

    fixedMenu();

    $(window).on('scroll' , function(){
        fixedMenu();
    });
});
```

[Site URL is here](http://latva.itwebdev.net/services/)

Edit: [Here's a video of the problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zpNXX3vCfGA)

Comment: Aside from some layout weirdness, the menu works fine for me in desktop Chrome ([img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TR7XR.png))

Comment: @MTCoster yes, I mentioned that it works fine on chrome. It's only when you use an actual Apple device it doesn't work properly.

Comment: Oh my mistake, I interpreted your question backwards. That said, it also works fine for me on iOS Safari ([img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8c1lW.png))

Comment: @MTCoster try clicking on one of the dropdown items. I have a video of the problem here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zpNXX3vCfGA